# gwt visualization table, add scroll bar and width is no longer fitted

Tags: gwt, scrollbar, visualization

I am using the gwt visualization API. I use the Table widget and would like to specify the height using the `setHeight()` method.

[image]

When I put enough records, the vertical scroll bar shown up. The width of the table no longer fit the data after the scroll bar show up. The column labels are long records are forced to split to two lines:

[image]

How can I avoid it ?
(I don't want to fix the width of the table as the data is dynamic and I will add arbitrary columns also).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not particularly familiar with the "gwt visualization API" but the the first solution which comes to mind, is that you always show the scroll bars and make the field a little bit bigger.

Her a little code example:

```
ScrollPanel sp = new ScrollPanel();
sp.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
```

or if you are using UiBinder:

```
    <g:ScrollPanel ui:field="scrollPanel" alwaysShowScrollBars="true">
```

You can also let a scroll panel appear in the bottom  so your lines still appear in the bottom, but I don't thin that's what you want...

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: It seems gwt visualization is too primitive for my appl. I am now working with smart gwt, although it is quite heavy.